# Start Log4jServletContextListener with Spring Web App

Tags: logging, log4j, tomcat7, log4j2

I try to configure the log4j to my spring web project but unfortunately the Log4jServletContextListener didn't start and I didn't know why.

I was following the urls bellow:
- [Log4j2 creates log file but doesn't write to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162164/log4j2-creates-log-file-but-doesnt-write-to-it)
- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html

Although I follow the configuration in that links, my Log4j2 doesn't start. On console I don't see the next lines:

```
INFO  Log4jServletContextListener ensuring that Log4j starts up properly.
INFO  Log4jServletFilter initialized.
```

I run the app at Tomcat 7.0.59. Any idea about this problem?

Thanks ;P

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...I'm running the Tomcat in debug mode and my log4j2 had this config on top the file:

- status="WARN"

I change to WARN for DEBUG and log4j2 starts work. Where can I find more information about this tag in xml?